# Can I mix asphalt debris with concrete?

Tags: concrete

Can I mix the broken pieces, large whole pieces of the previous asphalt driveway that we demolished into the new concrete driveway in order to save on the cost of the concrete?

Answer (score 3):

Crushed (recycled) asphalt can make a decent *base* for concrete, assuming it's compacted well, but it shouldn't be mixed, for several reasons:

- It's softer, so it creates potential for compression in the slab.
- It's softer, so it will wear away on the surface, leaving depressions that will shorten slab life and make it less useful and attractive.
- It's a different color and contains crude oil. Your slab will look mottled.
- It may actually affect the cure of the concrete, which is a chemical process. This could weaken the slab.
- It may affect how moisture acts on the slab, especially in freezing climates.

Fun fact: Asphalt pavement *is* concrete, at least in industry terms. It's just a different recipe of ingredients.

Answer (score -1):

**Can** you? Sure. You can mix dirt or trash into it too.

Is it **a good idea**? No.

Comment: This answer could benefit from an explanation of *why* you don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Feel free to write a better one, and I'll even upvote it.

Comment: Steal crip659's comment from the OP and add it in.There's your problem.  ;)

Comment: Size of chunk is as much of a problem as softness.